# dialog internationalization in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, internationalization, translation

I fount a problem in my code because it translates some words (in this case a button) according to the language of the os. I've searched for solutions but I didn't find anything to fit my case. As far as I've seen bundles are used to translate strings.

Here is my problem explicitly:
[image]

My problem is that instead of cancel it writes "Annuler", the french word.

Here is the code for the dialog:

```
printerSet.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            ChoiceDialog<String> dialog = new ChoiceDialog<>(
                    "Dummy Printer", choices);
            dialog.setTitle("Choice Dialog");
            dialog.setHeaderText(null);
            dialog.setContentText("Choose the printer you want to use:");

            Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
            if (result.isPresent()) {
                String opt = result.get();
                System.out.println("Your choice: " + opt);
                printerLabel.setText("Selected Printer: " + opt);
            }

            printButton.setDisable(true);
            name.setText("");
            code.setText("");
            description.setText("");
            availability.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to provide the following JVM arguments at start-up:

```
java -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved at runtime by using `Locale.setDefault(locale)` in the `main` method of the `Application` class.

For example:

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);

        try {
            launch(args);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Handle error
        }
    }

}
```

Calling `Locale.setDefault(locale)` again after `Application.launch()` has been called, had no effect on the dialog button texts.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the buttons manually:

[MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceDialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MCVE extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

         ChoiceDialog<String> dialog = new ChoiceDialog<>(
                 "Dummy Printer");
         dialog.setTitle("Choice Dialog");
         dialog.setHeaderText(null);
         dialog.setContentText("Choose the printer you want to use:");

         // Remove the default buttons and then add your custom ones.
         dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().clear();
         dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(
                new ButtonType("OK", ButtonData.OK_DONE));
         dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(
                new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE));

         Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
         if (result.isPresent()) {
             String opt = result.get();
             System.out.println("Your choice: " + opt);
         }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the problem in the question and and issue with
Umlauts in the controlsfx wizard

see https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/769/encoding-problem-all-german-umlauts-are

I am using the following method:
after changing the locale I call refreshI18n() on my wizardpanes I use a derived WizardPane for that. refreshI18n() will call fixButtons() and there the button text is set newly according to the set locale.

The main issue is to find the controls and reset the text e.g. for Buttons

```
/**
* https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/769/encoding-problem-all-german-umlauts-are
* 
* @param wizardPane
*/
protected void fixButtons() {
  ButtonType buttonTypes[] = { ButtonType.NEXT, ButtonType.PREVIOUS,
    ButtonType.CANCEL, ButtonType.FINISH };
  for (ButtonType buttonType : buttonTypes) {
    Button button = findButton(buttonType);
    if (button != null) {
      button.setText(buttonType.getText());
    }
  }
}

/**
 * get the Button for the given buttonType
 * @return the button
 */
public Button findButton(ButtonType buttonType) {
  for (Node node : getChildren()) {
    if (node instanceof ButtonBar) {
      ButtonBar buttonBar = (ButtonBar) node;
      ObservableList<Node> buttons = buttonBar.getButtons();
      for (Node buttonNode : buttons) {
        Button button = (Button) buttonNode;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ObjectProperty<ButtonData> prop = (ObjectProperty<ButtonData>) button
          .getProperties().get("javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData");
        ButtonData buttonData = prop.getValue();
        if (buttonData.equals(buttonType.getButtonData())) {
          return button;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```